# Bug in C# code equivalent of Silverlight xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

Why does the following C# code not produce the equivalent of my Silverlight code?

XAML

```
    <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="White" Height="70" BorderThickness="4">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Margin="5,0,0,0" BorderBrush="White" Height="45" Width="45" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" Background="White">
                <Image Source="/Crystal%20Cloud;component/Resources/Images/weapons/swords/sword_0.png" />
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Wooden Dagger" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" />
                <TextBlock Text="DPS: 1" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

C#

```
    private Border CreateListItem(Item item)
    {
        // Main border
        Border itemBorder = new Border();
        itemBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(4);
        itemBorder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(8);
        itemBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        itemBorder.Height = 70;

        // Main stack panel
        StackPanel mainPanel = new StackPanel();
        mainPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        itemBorder.Child = mainPanel;

        // The item's image border
        Border imageBorder = new Border();
        imageBorder.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0);
        itemBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
        itemBorder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(2);
        itemBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        itemBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        itemBorder.Height = 45;
        itemBorder.Width = 45;
        mainPanel.Children.Add(imageBorder);

        // The item's image
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Crystal%20Cloud;component/Resources/Images/weapons/swords/sword_0.png"));
        imageBorder.Child = image;

        // The stack panel for the text
        StackPanel textPanel = new StackPanel();
        textPanel.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
        mainPanel.Children.Add(textPanel);

        // The title text block
        TextBlock titleText = new TextBlock();
        titleText.Text = "Wooden Dagger";
        titleText.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS");
        textPanel.Children.Add(titleText);

        // The status text block
        TextBlock statusText = new TextBlock();
        statusText.Text = "DPS: 1";
        statusText.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS");
        statusText.FontSize = 16;
        statusText.Margin = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0);
        textPanel.Children.Add(statusText);

        return itemBorder;
    }
```

Comment: What's the difference? What does one do that the other doesn't?

Comment: What are the differences in the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erg... just found the bug itemBorder should be changed to imageBorder.